# Clang on Amazon Linux from EPEL can't find C++ headers or libraries

Tags: c++, linux, amazon-web-services, centos, clang

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world test program just to get things working on our CI infrastructure build boxes and it refuses to compile on CentOS with clang (but works fine with GCC on the same platform). For completeness, here is the obviously trivial program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "wow" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Running `clang++ test.cpp` yields:

> test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found

I installed it with a simple `sudo yum install clang` and can see that when GCC gets installed on Amazon Linux it comes with its own libstdc++ headers which are in /usr/include/c++/gcc-version but it seems odd to have to specify includes to compile something like this.

Clang should be using its own (possibly libc++) instead and know where the headers and libs are on the system by default (for something like iostream at least).

Compiling and running the program works just fine with GCC here. It seems like the EPEL package for clang may not have been configured correctly, is this the case? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm forced to use RHEL 6.4 on my work, and from my point of view the huge part of packages in this distro is outdated. GCC 4.4 supports less then a half of C++11 features. I guess that Clang from repo is quite old too (3.0?). If it's not a secret, what's the profit from the use of the one? Or maybe you have CentOS 7 beta on-board?

Comment: @VitalyIsaev it's not, the one from EPEL is Clang 3.4 which is current and modern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the "triples" not being defined to support Amazon Linux. See [original patch](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-November/025666.html) and [application for EPEL on EL6](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/llvm-3.4-10.el6).

Comment: Hah, yes, glad we squashed this one.

Answer (score 2):

As Dave mentioned, he has created new RPM packages which are now in EPEL testing. You can install them on Amazon Linux right now like this:

```
yum --enablerepo=epel-testing --nogpgcheck install clang
```

Once the packages are tested further they will be in EPEL proper (stable) and be installable using clang install.